# Complex Updates in MongoDb 2.6

Tags: mongodb

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154639/mongodb-complex-query-on-nested-array

[MongoDB 2.2 - Updating Array Nested Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692728/mongodb-2-2-updating-array-nested-document)

## Are these updates possible with MongoDb 2.6 ??

## DETAILS

I have a single document in MongoDb whose structure is something like this .. NESTED ARRAY. I want to $addToSet into d:["x","y"] to make it d:["x","y","z"].

I have tried out $elemMatch and $. But they only work at a SINGLE LEVEL of array.

```
{
 id:1,
 a:[
     {
        id:2,
        b:[
            {
                id:3,
                c:[
                    {
                        id:4,
                        d:["x","y"]
                    },
                    {
                        id:5,
                        d:["p","q"]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id:13,
                c:[
                    {
                        id:14,
                        d:["w","q"]
                    },
                    {
                        id:15,
                        d:["i","j"]
                    }
                ]
            }           
        ]   
     }
 ]
}
```

What will be the query to get d:["x","y","z"] where query part could be .. {id:1, "a.id":2, "a.b.id":3, "a.b.c.id":4 } or may be using $elemMatch ?

## REQUIREMENTS

NEED an exact update query for updating `d` to d:["x","y","z"] ;

$addToSet or any other operator to add "z" to the matched d:[]

PROBLEM : And what will be there in the update part how "$" will be replaced to index ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongodb complex query on nested array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154639/mongodb-complex-query-on-nested-array)

Comment: Why are you posting the question for the second time. Even if people tried to close it?

Comment: @naveen You should probably delete your earlier identical question with 0 answers...

Comment: Ok, i have closed the duplicate.. don't know how i got that .. probably because i seriously wanted this feature to come in MongoDb, and according to me this is  a serious incomplete feature of doing updates to document in mongodb 2.4/2.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) as follows.

```
{
  a: {
    $elemMatch: {
      id: 2,
      b: {
        $elemMatch: {
          id: 3,
          c: {
            $elemMatch: {
              id: 4
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what will be there in the update part how "$" will be replaced to index .. can you give me the exact update query for updating `d` to d:["x","y","z"] ; $push "z" to the matched d:[]

Comment: so i assume the issue is still unreolved